# JQuery datatable didnt update number of data after filtering

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, datatables, server-side

I have a JQuery DataTable which already bind with Server Side Processing. However, once I want to filter the data, it return to the Generic Handler, it is being filtered, but it didn't update the number of data. Image below shows what I mean:

[image]

The code:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="tblMember">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Account</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#tblMember").DataTable({
            pagingType: "simple_numbers",
            bLengthChange: false,
            bProcessing: true,
            bServerSide: true,
            bSort: false,
            iDisplayLength: 10,
            sAjaxSource: "../Retrieve.ashx",
            fnServerData: function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                aoData.push({ "name": "GroupAccount", "value": "GroupAccount" })

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: aoData,
                    url: sSource,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        fnCallback(msg);
                    }
                });
            },
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    width: "10%",
                    className: "dt-body-center",
                    targets: -1,
                    defaultContent: ["<i class='fa fa-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></i><i class='fa fa-trash-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>"]
                }
            ]
        });
```

**Retrieve.ashx:**

```
public Member Model;

public int sEcho { get; set; }
public string sSearch { get; set; }
public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
public int iTotalRecords { get; set; }
public int iTotalDisplayRecords { get; set; }
public IList<string[]> aaData;

public int echo { get; set; }
public int displayLength { get; set; }
public int displayStart { get; set; }
public string sort { get; set; }
public string search { get; set; }
public int sortCol { get; set; }

public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
base.ProcessRequest(context);

GetDataTableRequest(context);

Model = GetMemberData(displayStart, search, displayLength);

List<string[]> aaData = Model.Select(r => new[]
{
    r.Name,
    r.Gender,
    r.Status,
     r.Account
}).ToList();

context.Response.ContentType = ContentType.JSON;
      context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SetResponse(echo, search, Model.Count, Model.TotalRows, aaData)));
}

public void GetDataTableRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    this.echo = int.Parse(context.Request.Params["sEcho"]);
    this.displayLength = int.Parse(context.Request.Params["iDisplayLength"]);
    this.displayStart = int.Parse(context.Request.Params["iDisplayStart"]);
    this.sort = (context.Request.Params["sSortDir_0"] ?? "desc").ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    this.search = context.Request.Params["sSearch"];
    this.sortCol = int.Parse(context.Request.Params["iSortCol_0"] ?? (byte.MinValue).ToString());
}

public void SetResponse(int echo, string searchKey, int records, int totalRecords, List<string[]> aaData)
{
    this.sEcho = echo;
    this.sSearch = searchKey;
    this.recordsTotal = records;
    this.recordsFiltered = records;
    this.iTotalRecords = totalRecords;
    this.iTotalDisplayRecords = totalRecords;
    this.aaData = aaData;
}
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT * FROM [Member] WHERE [GroupAccount] = @GroupAccount AND [Name] LIKE %search% ORDER BY [Name] ASC OFFSET (displayStart / (displayLength - 1)) * displayLength ROWS FETCH NEXT displayLength ROWS ONLY
```

How can I update the number of data after filtering?

Comment: You'll need to filter your data in **Retrieve.ashx**. Looking at your code, it looks like you aren't applying any of the given filters to your data before writing it to your response.

Comment: Hi, how can I do that? can give me an example to achieve that? Thanks a lot

Comment: I've always implemented my filters using LINQ (never managed to do it in a clean way), but since you're retrieving your data using SQL, try the following `WHERE` statement: 

`WHERE ( columnName LIKE '%SearchValue%' OR otherColumnName LIKE '%SearchValue%' )` to your SQL.

There is probably a cleaner way to do this using SQL, I'm not sure if it is possible, but you could select the columns you want to match the search with in a variable, match the selected column values dynamically.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. But, this question always makes me wonder, why every time I go to the next or previous or input value to the search box in the JQuery Data Table, it always go to the server to make the request again. Does it same like when I implement my own table? I thought that JQuery Data Table request one time only, and whatever action I make to the JQuery Data Table, will be done on the client side (not required to request from the server and database again)

Comment: When you enable server side processing, every change gets passed to the server to update the data. With smaller data sets this can be overkill, but when you're working with large datasets, it's a necessity. If your data set is small enough, you can disable server side processing and load the data directly into your DataTable. This allows client side filtering/sorting etc.

Comment: Hi @DannyBogers, thank you very much on the explanation and also the suggestion above to make the search working. It is working now, but I have problem where the number of data is not updated, while the records are being filtered. Please take a look at my question again, I have updated it. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124156/discussion-between-danny-bogers-and-nies).